# AngularJS : Why is my watch not firing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am sure this will be one of those "duh" things, but i cant seem to figure out why my watch within my directive is firing.

I have a directive that is going to write out something about the item that is in question.  I have tried to refer to the item via

```
scope: {
    item: '=criteriaDescription'
}
```

as well as using $parse, so i do not have to have an isolated scope, neither seem to work, as my 'changed' code aint being called.  here is my directive

```
angular.module('app').directive('criteriaDescription', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var item = $parse(attrs.criteriaDescription)(scope);

            // generate a description for this criteria item, based on values and options
            scope.$watch(function () {
                return item;
            }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                var desc = 'You have a name of ' + newValue.name;

                element.html(desc);
            });

        }
    };
}]);
```

My HTML that uses the directive looks like this, as you can see i am showing name outside of the directive and it updates when i change it.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in report.criteria">
    <td>
        <h5 ng-bind="item.name"></h5>
        <span criteria-description="item"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to parse.

Try this..

```
scope.$watch(attrs.criteriaDescription, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                var desc = 'You have a name of ' + newValue.name;

                element.html(desc);
            }, true);
```

In the code snippet that you have given,

`var item = $parse(attrs.criteriaDescription)(scope);`

This will be evaluated at the start of the link function.

As this value is evaluated only once, it will not change.

Hence your watch is not getting fired.

Comment: Nope still not working, plus this isnt good, as the variable is only called item because its within ng-repeat.  If i used it in another place, i could not guarntee that the object would be in a scope variable called item

Comment: instead of using the 'item' we can use `attrs.criteriaDescription`. If it still doesn't work. Can you create a plunker/fiddle?

Comment: Here is a fiddlehttp://jsfiddle.net/exzm4e79/1/.  Change the value in the textbox and notice that the directive doesnt change

Comment: As the item as Array in your case, and as the reference is not changing, you need to create a deep watch. Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/exzm4e79/2/

Answer (score 1):

Since the scope is isolated you can use access `scope.items` and watch for it changes using [`$watchCollection`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection):

```
angular.module('app').directive('criteriaDescription', [function () {
    'use strict';

    return {
        scope: {
            item: '=criteriaDescription'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watchCollection('item', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                var desc = 'You have a name of ' + newValue.name;
                element.html(desc);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/hSrRyKM8LQbp5evbaywD?p=preview

You could also use [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) with the third parameter `true` to force deep object comparison to detect changes:

```
scope.$watch('item', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    var desc = 'You have a name of ' + newValue.name;
    element.html(desc);
}, true);
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/0FzVl5lJ3ahtOB5cIUdw?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work.  Do i need to have an isolated scope here though, can the same functionality be achieved without the directive having an isolated scope?

Comment: Yes, it can be. In this case you simply use `scope.$watch('item', function() {})`. Check this demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/0FzVl5lJ3ahtOB5cIUdw?p=preview But I would not recommend this appoach as it's not flexible at all, since you depend in the name of the variable to be `item` in outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a custom directive? Can't you just do it like this?

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in report.criteria">
    <td>
        <h5 ng-bind="item.name"></h5>
        <span>You have a name of {{item.name}}</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I have stripped the directive down, to be very simple.  So yeah i need the directive